# Búsqueda inteligente basada en txt

Tags: java, txt

Necesito hacer una búsqueda inteligente con base en txt en java.

> El pasajero tendrá la posibilidad de realizar búsquedas inteligentes
> de vuelos con el fin de encontrar los mejores precios para su viaje.
>
> El pasajero indicará el nombre y/o IATA de los aeropuertos de origen y
> destino, las fechas para el viaje y como dato adicional un rango +/-
> de días (es un número) en los que desea viajar

Eso es lo que tengo que hacer y no sé cómo.

Este es mi código, solo busca, pero necesito que busque inteligentemente:

```
  public void BuscarLogin(File archivo, String vuelo,String pais){
    try {
        
        if(archivo.exists()) {
            
            BufferedReader leerArchivo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));
           
            String lineaLeida;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "*******Buscando*************");
           
            while((lineaLeida = leerArchivo.readLine()) != null) {
                
                String[] palabras = lineaLeida.split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++) {
                    if (palabras[i].equals(pais)){
                        
                    }
                    for (int x = 0; i < palabras.length; x++) {
                        if (palabras[x].equals(vuelo)) {
                            
                            

                            
                         

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
       
    } catch(Exception e) {
        
    }
    
}
```